# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name error

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts-action, struts2-namespace

This is the error messages:

> WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'welcome' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.

I have tried to put the struts under `WEB-INF/classes` already but it still doesn't work. I haven been stuck here a couple days now, please help.

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 3.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login">
        <result>login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="welcome" class="com.struts3.LoginAction" method="execute">
        <result name="SUCCESS">welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

[image: directory structure]

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome to Struts 2</h3>
<s:form action="welcome">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="password" label="Password" type="password"></s:textfield>
    <s:submit value="Login"></s:submit>
</s:form>   
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome To Struts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome <s:property value="username"/></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Basic Struts2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: error message]
[image: error]

Comment: The error message in the title and the one in the question are different. So which one do you get? There is no such thing yet `DTD Struts Configuration 3.0`. Show your jsp.

Comment: yeah, it should be `DTD Struts Configuration 2.5`. Also I posted my jsp

Comment: You're not using S2 `2.5`. Don't use dtd for `2.5`. It is just a warning. Is something not working?

Comment: when I sumbit the form, it wont show up welcome page, it displays http 404 error

Comment: The error message in the title

Comment: Your image displays different warning.

Comment: I added two images display the error after I click submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

The **struts.xml** configuration file must be on the root of the classpath, then on `WEB-INF/classes`, not in subpackages.

It should be put somewhere under `src`, and **be copied to `WEB-INF/classes` at build-time** by your favorite build-tool (Eclipse, Ant, Maven, ecc).

Comment: so I put my **struts.xml** under `src` but it didn't cope the **struts.xml** to the `WEB-INF/classes` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Your build tool MUST copy the struts.xml from its original location (`src/whatever`, for example `src/main/resources`) to `WEB-INF/classes`. If it doesn't, this is another problem that you should fix before coming back to this one. When it will copy the struts.xml in `WEB-INF/classes`, it should work.